# How to create BitArray for Code128Reader().decodeRow(...) method in Android, java?

Tags: android, byte, zxing, bitarray

I have the next issue. To get an image from a camera (`android.hardware.Camera`). Then crop the image and leave only one row of pixsels, horizontal row in the middle of the image. This row will be represented a byte array (`byte[]`) with a data in format NV21 (or YCbCr_420_SP). Then I need to submit this row into a method

```
Code128Redaer.decodeRow(int rowNumber, BitArray row, Map<DecodeHintType,?> ints)
```

, ZXing library. But i don't understand, how to convert my byte[] to a BitArray? Or how to decode my row? I don't want to use

```
decode(BinaryBitmap image)
```

because i think it will be slowlier.